# Move bucket file to other bucket with googleCloudStorageR library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a R script in a docker in order to execute it on Google Cloud Run.

After full treatment of a file X.csv located in bucket "Input", I want to migrate it to bucket "Done".
How to do it with googleCloudStorageR?

```
`googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload("myfile.csv")`
```

seems no offer a gs:// syntax:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload("gs://Input/X")
```

returns an error:

```
 Path 'gs://Input/X.csv' does not exist
```

Additionaly bucket name is not in gcs_upload() function arguments. Previsouly do I have to set the default bucket to "Done"?

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_global_bucket("Done")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cran.r-project this [Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleCloudStorageR/vignettes/googleCloudStorageR.html) shows how to upload objects

```
## upload a file - type will be guessed from file extension or supply type  
write.csv(mtcars, file = filename)
gcs_upload(filename)

## upload an R data.frame directly - will be converted to csv via write.csv
gcs_upload(mtcars)

## upload an R list - will be converted to json via jsonlite::toJSON
gcs_upload(list(a = 1, b = 3, c = list(d = 2, e = 5)))

## upload an R data.frame directly, with a custom function
## function should have arguments 'input' and 'output'
## safest to supply type too
f <- function(input, output) write.csv(input, row.names = FALSE, file = output)

gcs_upload(mtcars, 
           object_function = f,
           type = "text/csv")
```

If you are using [cloudyr](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR)

```
gcs_upload(
  file,
  bucket = gcs_get_global_bucket(),
  type = NULL,
  name = deparse(substitute(file)),
  object_function = NULL,
  object_metadata = NULL,
  predefinedAcl = c("private", "bucketLevel", "authenticatedRead",
    "bucketOwnerFullControl", "bucketOwnerRead", "projectPrivate", "publicRead",
    "default"),
  upload_type = c("simple", "resumable")
)

gcs_upload_set_limit(upload_limit = 5000000L)
```

if you want to set the bucket:

```
## set global bucket so don't need to keep supplying in future calls
gcs_global_bucket("my-bucket")
```

You can find this doc in the directory:

> googleCloudStorageR-master/docs/reference/gcs_upload.html